# NetBeans Change Ant Version

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I'm using NetBeans to build my project. The version I'm using is 1.8. However, I'm trying to build it again on a computer that can only run ant 1.6.5. Is there any way to specify in Netbeans which version of ant to use?

Comment: Do not forget to upvote or choose the answer of @Yogendra as the right one if you are satisfied with it. Actually I second his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow 3 easy steps as below:

1. Download `Ant 1.6.5` from [**Apache Binaries**](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/) and install/extract in your local file system
2. Go to `Netbeans Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Ant`
3. Change the `Ant Home` to `Ant 1.6.5 folder` created in step-1 of your local file system

**EDIT:**

If the above doesn't help because of your specific Net Beans, try steps below:

1. Go to `Help -> Help Contents`
2. Search for `Switching Ant Version`
3. Click the same link from left pane to get the details in right, you should see a screen as below:

[image]

Follow the instructions on the above page.

Comment: I did as you said but my build.impl.xml is still the 1.8 ant xml file. I tried deleting it for it to be regenerated but no cigar. it also doesn't compile/run - when I press run netbeans says my program is running but nothing happens.

Comment: Which version of Netbeans and Java, are you using?

Comment: Added new set of inputs. See if that helps you.

Comment: java 1.7.0_04. Netbeans 7.2 201207171143. Hmm, apparently there's an error message that occurs. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Input$Handler
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
....
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Input$Handler
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)

Comment: I found the setting in `Tools > Options > Java > Ant` in version 7.2

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans 8.2, go to `Tools -> Options -> Java -> Ant -> Ant Home`

[image]